# Unexpected behaviour of tailable cursor with mongos

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm triyng to change my MongoDB replica set to shard cluster. I have the following code in my app:

```
var cursor = _messages
    .Find(Query<Message>.GTE(x => x.Timestamp, fromTimestamp))
    .SetFlags(QueryFlags.TailableCursor | QueryFlags.AwaitData)
    .SetMaxTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("$natural"));

foreach (var message in enumerateCursor(cursor, cancellationToken))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

As you can see, it creates a tailable cursor and pass `AwaitData` flag to tell server that it should not return immidiatelly if there is no data that matches the query yet. `enumerateCursor` method has a fallback if mongo server does not support wait on tailable cursor, something like this:

```
    private static IEnumerable<Message> enumerateCursor(MongoCursor<Message> messages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var cursor = new MongoCursorEnumerator<Message>(messages))
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // some other code to enumerate a cursor...
            // ...and here comes the fallback:
            if (!cursor.IsServerAwaitCapable)
            {
                _logger.Warn("Server await is disabled, falling back to polling.");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            }
        }
    }
```

So my issue is: if I replace my app MongoDB connection string to connect to mongos (shard cluster) instead of mongod (replica set), `cursor.IsServerAwaitCapable` is equal to `false`, so instead of waiting for new data, I have to constantly poll my database server.

Does anyone know if it is a limitation of mongos or there is some subtle setting that cause this behaviour?

I use:

- MongoDB v. 3.2.11
- MongoDB C# driver v. 1.10.0.62